# RSA Encryption in PHP

Tags: php, rsa, phpseclib

I am not an expert in Encryption and I've spent hours searching the Internet and stackoverflow.com for answers, however I am still stuck.
My Problem is, that I have a Public Key Modulus and a Public Key Exponent, both given. With those, I need to encrypt a message.

Examples:

**mod:**
CA498337FDD3D7C5487DBE5101899309B51B9B4708E647F85CC599A6C96ADFF62D7CD6A184DF346A3F707E7A34C5853ABA9030C65773AF604C59B8ED2E78D869F26B57E03CA9D0D45C67B8791AB010482224D108FCE20B515D8B1904B4DB41D0003950245E2382CA62477727E543850BC4FD4235041A44F213A99514EF5F64BE3D7F9DEE9E383062078D4E64ED92A42B94A0466B5BC36DAC55499DEA719A38C3A0C287724F57C64507AB424E9DBCC7F93112CF38D1B5458BFCD454F4907C5A617EBCD0F79DE40BBF8971D7CF225D9425010CF5CF638EF00B2582CDE7EA41DF7D65419B4129BBD37A872372D270B537B95C2DEE078107515B8CE719D5020CF337

**exp:**
010001

I still cant figure out how to achieve this in PHP. This is the code I have so far (I'm using phpseclib):

```
$message = "Hello World";

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey(
array(
    'e' => new Math_BigInteger($pubkey_exp),
    'n' => new Math_BigInteger($pubkey_mod)
)
);

$rsa->setPublicKey();

$ciphertext = $rsa->encrypt($message);
```

However, I am not getting any output from this.

Comment: When i vardump the contents, it just gives me bool(false). Am I approaching this the right way?

Comment: Yes, the public key is properly defined. However, I made a mistake when copying the code to this post, Ive fixed the last line now(in the encrypt function, i am actually encrypting the message, not the public key). Still, I am not getting any output. Does the code work for you then?

Comment: This might make it easier: https://github.com/paragonie/EasyRSA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$pubkey_n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
$pubkey_e = '010001';
$message = "Hello World";

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$r = $rsa->loadkey(
    array(
      'e' => new Math_BigInteger($pubkey_e, 16),
      'n' => new Math_BigInteger($pubkey_n, 16)
    ),
    CRYPT_RSA_PUBLIC_FORMAT_RAW
);
//$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);
var_export( $ciphertext = $rsa->encrypt($message) );
```

seems to be working.